# What's the function to find a city nearest to a given latitude?

Tags: geography

I have recently started programming in Mathematica and I am currently struggling to find a way to locate the nearest city based on a given latitude. I have looked into `GeoPosition` and `GeoNearest`, but I find all these functions a bit confusing.

If someone could point me in the right direction or guide me, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! So if I understand correctly: You are looking at the circle on the Earth with given latitude, and you want to find the city with this latitude? Most likely, there will be many cities that are  crossed by this latitude ... So are you sure you want just one of them? The centerpoint (coordinates) of the city are somehow arbitrarily defined.

Comment: Thank you! Mathematica feels a bit overwhelming from writing Python :) With all these given functions and symbols. But, hoping to find supportive community.

Comment: I suggest reading [The Wolfram Language: Fast Introduction for Programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) which includes notes for people comming from Python background.

Comment: @Domen I read that tutorial, with my horror, saw only one YouTube video that used Mathematica and the guy started to write ```Prepend``` inside a function and I was like WHAT! And that fast introduction does not involve much with loops and functions in general, so not provided much help, unfortunately!

Comment: That is because loops (do, while, for) are very rarerly used in Mathematica. You just have to get used that there are some _conceptual_ differences between the two languages. I strongly suggest you read through the tutorial (also [Stephen Wolfram
An Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/3rd-ed/) because it will save you a lot of confusion.

Comment: Aha! Thanks for the pointer. I am trying to teach myself the conceptual differences but lacking a clear guide on how to do it. If you could point to a direction, that'll be amazing!

Comment: @MarcoB & Domen Thanks a lot for the assistance! I went through the tutorials and now a lot makes sense. MarcoB actually my comment got posted after 30s/1min Domen replied as Stack does not refresh continuously. But, again thanks for being supportive, guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`GeoNearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoNearest.html) and [`GeoPath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPath.html).

```
latitude = 46.06;

cities = GeoNearest["City", GeoPath[{"Parallel", latitude}], {All, 0}, 
 DistanceFunction -> "Center"]
(* {Entity["City", {"Dobrova", "Osrednjeslovenska", "Slovenia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"Ljubljana", "Osrednjeslovenska", "Slovenia"}], 
    Entity["City", {"Premariacco", "FriuliVeneziaGiulia", "Italy"}], 
    ...} *)

Length[cities]
(* 11 *)

Show[GeoGraphics[GeoPath[{"Parallel", latitude}]], GeoListPlot[cities]]
```

[image]

However, there are two problems. First, as shown above, there may be multiple cities having the exact same lattitude. Second, if no city is found at the exact lattitude, you will have to repeat the procedure repeatedly by increasing the allowed tolerance (set to 0 in the code above) until a match is found. This is because there seems to be a bug in `GeoNearest` when used with `GeoPath` so that results are not given in correct order.

If you want to restrict the search only to capitals, you can first get a list of all of them, then use it inside `GeoNearest`.

```
capitals = Map[CountryData[#, "CapitalCity"] &, CountryData["UN"]];
GeoNearest[capitals, GeoPath[{"Parallel", latitude}]]
(* {Entity["City", {"Ljubljana", "Osrednjeslovenska", "Slovenia"}]} *)
```

Now there are only two such lattitudes with more than one capital city:

```
Select[GatherBy[EntityValue[capitals, {"Name", "Latitude"}], Last], 
 Length[#] > 1 &] // Grid
(* {Beijing, 39.93°}, {Ankara, 39.93°}
   {Tehran, 35.67°}, {Tokyo, 35.67°} *)
```

Comment: for a given latitude, I want to find the closest city to it. That means If I use the function or code, I just type the latitude and my code will show the nearest city to that latitude. Can we do that?

Comment: Welcome Ammar, here is a hint to get you started in the right direction. Make a function that starts like findCitiesAtLatitude[latitude_, number_]:= Block[{cities=…..},…]

Comment: @Ammar, there is a problem with what you want. For example: both Ljubljana (Slovenia) and Madaras (Hungary) have the same latitude which you can see by evaluating `Entity["City", {"Ljubljana", "Osrednjeslovenska", "Slovenia"}]["Latitude"]` and `Entity["City", {"Madaras", "BacsKiskun", "Hungary"}]["Latitude"]`, both returning `Quantity[46.06, "AngularDegrees"]`. How to then choose one of them if you give lattitude 46.06?

Comment: @Domen Yes, you're right! Can we somehow just limit the function or code to show the nearest capital city of a given latitude?

Comment: @CraigCarter Thank you and I actually, thought of that, but, the functions to find the cities nearest to something, I am having a hard time to understand what to use or how to do that. 

Documentation is OKayish! And don't really have any further materials : ) Trying get to used to myself with mathematica, haha!

Comment: ```capitals = Map[CountryData[#, "CapitalCity"] &, CountryData["UN"]];``` In this code, can you kindly explain, What "#" suppose to mean? is it like a place holder like "_"? And ";" what does this symbol refers? Sorry If I'm asking too many basic questions. Completely new in this language.

Comment: @Ammar, I can, but I shall not :) As I suggested in the comments above, go through both tutorials _carefully_, without skipping sections, and you will find all of these explained. Note that when you open [The Wolfram Language: Fast Introduction for Programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/built-in-functions/), you should scroll down, click on _Python_, then _Get Started (with notes)_.

Comment: @Domen thanks for the notes suggestion and that cleared my doubts. Lucky to have a supportive community!